# Wild time differences measured in Node.js program

Tags: javascript, node.js, image

I've noticed an odd behavior in a program I am working on. While it's probably my fault, I wanted to check if someone faced this before.

Both with console.time and [performance-now](https://www.npmjs.com/package/performance-now) my code has highly variable run time. I can't exactly paste it here because it's work related, but the workflow is:

1. start timer
2. load image via [jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp)
3. when image is loaded, scale image times 2
4. scan the image, transform pixels in zeroes and ones and put it into an array
5. log time

Some discrepancy is sure to be expected, but the results are so different I'm wondering what I did wrong. Average time is short, but the outliers are pretty... well, you can see on the image below.

[image: Same 8x8 png image]

Comment: Have you tried checking times:
1. after the load
2. after the scale
3. after the scan?

Comment: Just tried that. There's odd times on all of them. The difference seems to come from jimp loading the image

Comment: Are you using the same image each time, or different ones?

Comment: Same 8x8 png, black and white image.

Comment: Could be caused by external reasons (lots of active CPU or I/O), could be garbage collection (take a look at [`gc-profiler`](https://github.com/bretcope/node-gc-profiler)).